# Adding and retrieving from sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using Angulars $window service for sessionStorage. What I need to do is to add the success of a promise from a service into the sessionStorage so that it can be used throughout the application.

Here's what I've been trying:

```
$window.sessionStorage.setItem('promoImages',success);
```

success is an array of objects returned from the service, in this structure:

```
[{
  promotion: {},
  url: 'images/image1.png'
 },
 {},
 {}];
```

So this structure should then be assigned to promoImages via the line above. However when I print the value like so:

```
 $log.debug('Promo from session:'+JSON.stringify($window.sessionStorage.promoImages));
```

I get the following:

```
Promo from session:"[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"
```

If I make the same move for both the success array and the session array I get different results - the session array returns **undefined** - why?

```
 $log.debug('Success:'+JSON.stringify(success[0].url));
 // Returns url above
 $log.debug('Promo from session:'+JSON.stringify($window.sessionStorage.promoImages[0].url));
 // Returns undefined
```

What am I doing wrong in regard to the sessionStorage? Can sessionStorage only be added to in the same file it was created in? (I don't think so).

Thanks

**EDIT**

Thanks to the guys below for their answers - but I think it's worth pointing out that the stringify function, when used on my object, actually added forward slashes into the object in place of the whitespace...

Comment: You should consider using IndexedDB (I'm not sure if there is any Angular service to deal with it).

Comment: @Ginden can you provide me with a good resource to read up on it - more for my own knowledge as the above is a project for work which is too late in the game to have this changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store only strings in sessionStorage so before store it, first do stringify() and at the time of retrieval again parse it to JSON.

at the time of saving:

```
$window.sessionStorage.setItem("JsonObj", JSON.stringify([
   {url: ""},{},{}
]));
```

at the time of retrieval:

```
JSON.parse($window.sessionStorage.JsonObj)[0].url
```

Comment: thanks for this - this works - it would help if I properly read the docs! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can only store strings in SessionStorage. Stringify your object before calling `setItem()`

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage.setItem):

> ## Storage.setItem
>
> ### Parameters
>
> #### key name
>
> A DOMString containing the name of the key you want to create/update.
>
> #### key value
>
> A DOMString containing the value you want to give the key you are creating/updating.